# One result from join between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

It is a bit complicated to explain into the main caption, but the situation is as follow :
- I have 2 tables :
Users,  Preferences.

defined as follow

Users :

```
ID | NAME | FK_NODE_PREFERENCES
```

Preferences :

```
ID | FK_USERS | PREFERENCE_DESCRIPTION
```

the idea is to have alot of preferences for each user...

the results shall look as follow :

```
USER | ALL_PREFERENCES
```

- I need to search by a part of the preference string and i need to have only 1 row into the result select query, which having all the preferences related ot the user as a text into a single record ?

Comment: Are you wanting to filter all the rows by a supplied preference fragment or are you wanting all rows returned as one row?

Comment: Why do you have cross FK between users table and nodepreferences? In Users FK_NODE_PREFERENCES and in NodePreferences FK_USERS? If you need work with infinite to infinite you might work with a cross reference table. as NodePreferences work with Preferences tables

Comment: i am not sure how to explain it - generally it shall be something like : if the user have choosed "RED","BLUE","WHITE" - they all shall persist into the result record ALL_PREFERENCECE with space separated as one string.

Comment: @Leandro - you actually have right. Thank you very much for the note you made :). i am modifing it right now toward your note, but the main question still remains. :|

Comment: modified the main question, i hope this headbanging could be solved :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Firebird, but it seems to have a LIST() function which should be an equivalent to the GROUP_CONCAT() function in MySQL. (see documentation of [`LIST()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-list))

So, basically the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT Users.name, LIST(Preferences.preference_description, ' ') AS ALL_PREFERENCES FROM Users JOIN NodePreferences ON Users.fk_node_preferences = Preferences.id WHERE Preferences.preference_description LIKE '%abc%' GROUP BY Users.name
```

So, I'm not sure if this actually works, but the direction should be the right one.

Comment: somehow i cant bring to life the query :|

Comment: can you give us the query you tried and the error message firebird gives you...?